# tee command piped in a grep and redirected to file

Tags: bash, tee

I would like to use the following command in bash:

```
(while true; do date; sleep 1;done) | tee out.out 2>&1 | grep ^[A-Z] >log.log 2>&1 &
```

unfortunately, until it is finished (by killing the ppid of sleep command for example), the file `log.log` is empty but the file `out.out` has the expected content.

1. I first want to understand what's happening
2. I would like to fix this.

Comment: `grep` buffers the file as it processes it. Use `grep --line-buffered '^[A-Z]'` to make it output lines as soon as it reads them. BTW, note that I put quotes around the regex -- it's unlikely to be a problem here, but without quotes the pattern might get expanded as a shell wildcard pattern before being passed to `grep`, which would give weird results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to fix this, you need to make `grep` line-buffered. This might depend on the implementation, but on BSD grep (shipped with Mac OS X), you simply need to add the `--line-buffered` option to `grep`:

```
(while true; do date; sleep 1;done) | tee out.out 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered ^[A-Z] >log.log 2>&1 &
```

From the `grep` man page:

```
--line-buffered
             Force output to be line buffered.  By default, output is line buffered when standard output is a terminal and block buffered otherwise.
```

You can actually validate that behavior by outputting to STDOUT instead:

```
(while true; do date; sleep 1;done) | tee out.out 2>&1 | grep ^[A-Z] 2>&1 &
```

In that case, you don't need to buffer by line explicitly, because that's the default. However, when you redirect to a file, you must explicitly set that behaviour.